# IBM Domino UserCertificate Field

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Does anyone know the format the UserCertificate field is stored in (DER, crt, etc)? I have not been able to extract this properly to calculate a fingerprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field is a hex-encoded field. The internet certificates were base64 encoded, so in my DSAPI filter, I pulled the cert, ran a Hex-To-Base64 Decoder and calculated a fingerprint.

Just an FYI, the first 44 numbers/letters of the encoded Cert are added by Domino and are not part of the cert.